# Change control access of custom objects for different users through apex

Tags: apex, soql, permissions, user, custom-permission

This is a generalized code of what I am trying to do.

```
TestNested__c[] myCustomObjList = [SELECT id, ownerId from TestNested__c];
String platformUserId = '005DP000007Yji5YAC';
String securityUserId = '005DP000007Yji1YAC';
for (TestNested__c obj : myCustomObjList) {
    // if current owner is platform user change it to integration user
    if(obj.ownerId == platformUserId) {
        obj.ownerId = securityUserId;
    }
}
update myCustomObjList;
```

The exception I get on this code is:

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 2 with id a09DP00000Fnq8cYAB; first error: TRANSFER_REQUIRES_READ, The new owner must have read permission: []

Upon checking the permission in profiles I noticed that the read/Write permission for custom objects is turned off for this user. So by default, the read/write permissions for my `security user` are turned off for custom objects. I can change these permissions through salesforce following this article.
[Change Control Access to Salesforce Objects and Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_security_salesforce_object_field_levels_control_access.htm&type=5)

Is there any way I can achieve this through apex?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify permissions directly in Apex.

You can create a Permission Set and assign it via Apex.